# Why LiveUSB wouldn't boot on Asus eeepc 1015cx netbook?

Tags: 12.04, boot, live-usb, ubuntu-netbook

I'm creating a USB disk for Ubuntu by iso2usb and I can't boot. I choose USB disk from beginning and it says eject disk or another media and press any key to restart. No setup page, no nothing.

How can I install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using USB installer provided at pendrivelinux( http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ ) to make your usb disk. You can find the tutorial [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). Also you may have to change your **boot options**.